# Could be duplicate records in many-to-many table?

Tags: mysql

I have table person, room and person_room.

When person entry to a room I'm creating new record in person_room.

But when the person leaves room should I:

1. Delete record in person_room ?
2. Create new record with bool information that person is gone?

Tables:

```
------------------
       ROOM
------------------
ID | Description |
------------------
      ...
4  | Kitchen
5  | Living room
      ...
------------------

------------------
      PERSON
------------------
ID | Description |
------------------
      ...
7  | Peter
8  | John
      ...
------------------

---------------------------------------------
                PERSON_ROOM
---------------------------------------------
ID | ROOM_ID | PERSON_ID | STATUS | CREATED |
---------------------------------------------
                    ...
---------------------------------------------
(Column status is bool, 1 - person entered, 0 - person walks away)
```

Example of 2)

When person 1 (Peter) entry to the room 1 (Kitchen)

```
---------------------------------------------
                PERSON_ROOM
------------------------------------------------
ID | ROOM_ID | PERSON_ID | STATUS | CREATED    |
------------------------------------------------
1  | 4       | 7         | 1      | 2016-02-05 |
------------------------------------------------
```

Then person 1 (Peter) leaves the room 1 (Kitchen)

```
---------------------------------------------
                PERSON_ROOM
------------------------------------------------
ID | ROOM_ID | PERSON_ID | STATUS | CREATED    |
------------------------------------------------
1  | 4       | 7         | 1      | 2016-02-05 |
2  | 4       | 7         | 0      | 2016-02-06 |
------------------------------------------------
```

It is good solution for tracking who is/was where, how long, entry counting etc..?

Comment: yeah, I think its a nice try and provides a good solution. so let it go ;)

Comment: Keeping **in** and **out** records YOU ARE NOT LOOSING THEM. that's the point.